# How do I interpret the output of `cargo bench`?

Tags: testing, rust, measurement

I benchmarked my Rust project with `cargo bench` and see many numbers on the results... What do they mean?

```
2 tests
test bench_few_core ... bench:  26,249,920 ns/iter (+/- 2,836,381)
test bench_one_core ... bench:   6,087,923 ns/iter (+/- 752,064)
```

For example for `test bench_few_core`, I see:

- number 1 = 26
- number 2 = 249
- number 3 = 920
- number 4 = 2
- number 5 = 836
- number 6 = 381

What do they all mean?

I thought there should be 2 numbers per test: math expectation (or mean) and standard deviation.

Comment: _"I thought there should be 2 numbers per test"_ And indeed there are two numbers for each benched function, as you did expect. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I edited the question be more specific about numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does show the two numbers you expect per test: the median and total deviation (i.e. `max-min`) in nanoseconds per iteration.

Note that for large numbers, it is standard practice in US English to write digits in groups of 3 separated by commas. For example, 26249920 is often written 26,249,920.

Comment: @Shepmaster do you have a link for that? Those numbers look awfully small for variances, but they look about right for standard deviations…

Comment: Looks like we are both wrong. According to [the source code](https://docs.rs/bencher/*/src/bencher/lib.rs.html#403) these numbers are actually the _median_ and the _total deviation_ (i.e. `max-min`).

Comment: Yep, was doing the same searching.

Answer (score 5):

The numbers are the [*median*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) and the *difference between the maximum and minimum*, expressed using US-centric number styles (which use the comma as the thousands separator).

For your example:

- median: 26249920 ns/iter
- max-min: 2836381 ns/iter

```rust
let median = bs.ns_iter_summ.median as usize;
let deviation = (bs.ns_iter_summ.max - bs.ns_iter_summ.min) as usize;

write!(
    output,
    "{:>11} ns/iter (+/- {})",
    fmt_thousands_sep(median, ','),
    fmt_thousands_sep(deviation, ',')
)
```

[source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.51.0/library/test/src/bench.rs#L56-L74)

Note that there's various statistical work [underlying the benchmarking](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.51.0/library/test/src/bench.rs#L111-L178), most obviously the fact that the upper and lower 5% of samples are truncated to reduce the effect of outliers.

Comment: @Alec uhh, no idea what went wrong there! My brain must have been stuck in one mode!