# Why is my program slower than the benchmark shows?

Tags: ubuntu, rust

I have this code:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "string";
    let res = fizz(s);
    println("{}", res);
}

fn fizz(s: &str) -> String {
    // Does something heavy
}

#[bench]
fn fizz_time(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let s = "string";
    b.iter(|| {
        fizz(s);
    });
}
```

The benchmark result is:

```
⟩ cargo bench
running 1 tests
test test::fizz_time ... bench:   8,215,412 ns/iter (+/- 681,134)
```

This indicates that takes about 8ms to execute the whole program, but when I run a executable built by `cargo build --release`, it takes about 50ms to execute:

```
⟩ time -v ./target/release/fizz_test 
03b14f36de9aa6c85a87f29cceb21c6f972e94170d8f32c321ae7b6785c4043b5f
        Command being timed: "./target/release/fizz_test"
        User time (seconds): 0.05
        System time (seconds): 0.00
        Percent of CPU this job got: 95%
        Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.06
        Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
        Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
        Average stack size (kbytes): 0
        Average total size (kbytes): 0
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2876
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
        Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
        Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 136
        Voluntary context switches: 0
        Involuntary context switches: 75
        Swaps: 0
        File system inputs: 0
        File system outputs: 0
        Socket messages sent: 0
        Socket messages received: 0
        Signals delivered: 0
        Page size (bytes): 4096
        Exit status: 0
```

Why would this happen? Is executing `main` a heavy task compared to the functions? Is the benchmark not properly written?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 64bit (kernel 4.13.0-36-lowlatency).

Comment: I don't know about linux, but on windows outputting to a file is much faster than outputting to a visible console. You might try redirecting the output to `/dev/nul`. And of course there is some startup overhead (create process, setup memory manager, cold caches, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be a combination of delay in console output, cold caches in the CPU (compared to `cargo bench`, which runs the benchmark multiple times) and linking.

One quick way to drill down is to time your `main()` using `std::time::Instant`. If this is closer to 8ms, it's most likely overhead in preparing execution (fork, link exec).

If you *really* want to know, system-wide profiling (i.e. `perf` in Linux) is probably the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The results *don't* indicate that it takes 8ms to run the whole program, but that it takes roughly 8ms to run the `fizz` function *once*. However, the bencher runs the function more than once to ensure that the results are repeatable. Hence the `+/- 681,134` which gives a measure of how much variation there was between runs.

More specifically, 8ms is the median time of several runs, while  `+/- 681,134 ns` is the difference between the maximum and minimum observed run times.

See also [How do I interpret the output of `cargo bench`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48323487/155423)